# How to calculate values in JavaScript using values from an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to calculate a simple multiplication in js, like this:
A * B = C
D * E = F
G * H = I
Grand Total = C + F + I

However, the grand total is much larger than is expected.  Is there a problem with my multiplication or am I reading the values from the page incorrectly?

Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  calculate = function(totalElement)
  {
      if (totalElement)
      {
          var calculation  = '';
          var overall = '';
          var fields = new Array();
          var theElement = document.getElementById(totalElement);
          var userInputs = myform.elements;
          var the_type = '';
          for (var f = 0; f < userInputs.length; f++)
          {
              if (userInputs[f].className=='special_value')
              {
                 if(userInputs[f].value != "")
                 {
                     document.getElementById("price4").value+=+userInputs[f].value;

                 }           

              }
          }


      }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform">
A<input onKeyPress="calculate('total');" onBlur="calculate('total');" class="special_value" value="" type="text" name="price"> 
B<input onKeyPress="calculate('total');" onBlur="calculate('total');" class="special_value" type="text" value="" name="price2"> 
C<input onKeyPress="calculate('total');" onBlur="calculate('total');" class="special_value" type="text"value=""  name="price4" id="price4"> <Br/>
D<input onKeyPress="calculate('total');" onBlur="calculate('total');" class="special_value" value="" type="text" name="price5"> 
E<input onKeyPress="calculate('total');" onBlur="calculate('total');" class="special_value" type="text" value="" name="price6"> 
F<input onKeyPress="calculate('total');" onBlur="calculate('total');" class="special_value" type="text"value=""  name="price7" id="price7"> <Br/>
Total<input class="special_value" value="" id="total" type="text" name="total"> <Br/>
<!-- <div id="total"></div> -->
<input onClick="calculate('total');" type="button" name="button" value="re-calculate">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *However, the values are going too large on me.* So what is the question?

Comment: whats going on here...document.getElementById("price4").value+=+userInputs[f].value; .. +=+ ... hmm..

Comment: This makes less sense than anything I've read in awhile: `A * B = C D* E = F G * H=I Grand Total = C + F + I,`.  This question in general makes no sense.

Comment: it makes sense to Diodues below, and his response was much appreciated!

Comment: What you are doing wrong is obvious.  What you're trying to achieve makes no sense.

Comment: In general, on this site, when someone says "this doesn't make sense" - the best response is to try to clarify. This gives more people an understanding of your problem space, which is likely to yield more frequent, more complete, more well-rounded answers which are of more use to the community. Alternatively, responding with "Yeah - well someone understood it!" leads the person asking for clarity to simply leave - when they might've helped you (and thus other people who eventually find this answer and need help).

Answer (score 5):

`document.getElementById("price4").value` is a string. You're likely concatenating strings, rather than doing math with them.

Try: `parseFloat(document.getElementById("price4").value)`

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to make it so that i can automatically multiply the numbers and assign the value?

Comment: Thanks Diodeus, a very simple calculation, i guess the main problem was the string concatenation. something that can overlook!